# Half of image blurred in elif statements

Tags: python, image, graphics

I am trying to make an image that is in quadrants with variations on the colours[image] in each one. I have managed to do half of the image, but the other half just blurs over - and there is no error message. Any idea what is going wrong? I want grayscale in the upper right, and black and white in the lower right

Here is my code:

```
import cImage as image

img = image.Image("/home/users/groth1/Downloads/selfie.JPG")
newimg = image.EmptyImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
win = image.ImageWin(title="Pic",width=img.getWidth(),height=img.getHeight())
img.draw(win)

xQuadrantBoundary = img.getWidth()//2
yQuadrantBoundary = img.getHeight()//2

for row in range(img.getHeight()):  
for col in range(img.getWidth()):
    p = img.getPixel(col, row)

    if row < yQuadrantBoundary:
        if col < xQuadrantBoundary:
            # upper left negative
            newred = 255 - p.getRed()
            newgreen = 255 - p.getGreen()
            newblue = 255 - p.getBlue()
            newpixel1 = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)

            img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel1)
        elif col >= xQuadrantBoundary:
           # upper right grayscale ***
            red = p.getRed()
            green = p.getGreen()
            blue = p.getBlue()
            avg = (red + green + blue) / 3.0
            newpixel2 = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)
            img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel2)

    elif row >= yQuadrantBoundary:
        if col < xQuadrantBoundary:
            #  lower left no green
            newred = p.getRed()
            newgreen = 0
            newblue = p.getBlue()
            newpixel3 = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)
            img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel3)
        elif col >= xQuadrantBoundary:
            #  lower right black and white ***
            red = p.getRed()
            if red > 140:
                val = 255
            else:
                val = 0
        newpixel4 = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)
        img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel4)

img.draw(win)
win.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newpixel2 = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)`

should be

`newpixel2 = image.Pixel(avg, avg, avg)`

and

`newpixel4 = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)`

should be

`newpixel4 = image.Pixel(val, val, val)`

else you are reusing the last computed `newred`, `newgreen`, and `newblue` values, hence the "streaks" of colors.